# IE 11 Textbox focus bug

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm stuck in a strange problem. I have a simple textbox which uses CSS. All browsers show it correctly and all except IE work with it correctly. The problem with IE is that sometimes I cannot click over the textbox so I can write text in it. When I click the box ... nothing happens.

Comment: I've noticed the same problem, using the uniform.js library. IE 11 often refuses focus on a textarea, especially if it is loaded in a document in an iframe. The only way I have been able to workaround the issue so far is to call .focus() on the textarea element in the onload event of the document.

Comment: So, did you ever find a solution?